# Corrent syntax for an ajax callback inline in Drupal 7

Tags: ajax

I have a custom block on my pages that displays total a total hit count amongst other stats for 'wiki' node types. For logged in users, I am able to increment this count each time straight in PHP but for anonymous users there is the page cache.

To get around this, I added a js ajax segment inline. The ajax calls the server for the latest data, which once received updates on the client side.

This is working successfully but I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a good solution to be doing what I want?
2. I've only just started using AJAX in D7. I couldn't figure it out, but could I do what i'm trying to do with the new [Ajax framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)?

The code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function wiki_menu() {
    $items = array();

  $items['wiki/ajax/stats/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'wiki_ajax_stats',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access callback' => '_wiki_ajax_stats_access',
    'access arguments' => array(3),
    'file' => 'wiki.pages.inc',     
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );  

    return $items;  
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function wiki_block_view($delta = '') {
    // Our blocks are set to only be visible on content types wiki and wiki_subpage 
    $node = menu_get_object();

    $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'stats':                       
            $block['subject'] = t('Statistics');

      if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
        // Path for ajax callback
        $url = url('wiki/ajax/stats/' . $node->book['bid']);

                // Add ajax callback inline for anonymous users
        drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {            
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "' . $url .  '",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
             jQuery("#block-wiki-stats td.today-value").text(data.today);
             jQuery("#block-wiki-stats td.total-value").text(data.total);
            }
          });
        });', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
      }
      else {
                _wiki_stats_increment($node->book['bid']);
      }

      $block['content'] = _wiki_block_stats($node);
      break;            
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * // Update the number of views for the node.
 */
function _wiki_stats_increment($nid) {
    db_update('wiki_stats')
        ->expression('today', 'today + :today', array(':today' => 1))
        ->expression('total', 'total + :total', array(':total' => 1))
        ->condition('nid', $nid)
        ->execute();    
}

/**
 * Callback for stats block
 *
 * @return
 *  Themed output for the activity block
 */
function _wiki_block_stats($node) {
    $stats = db_select('wiki_stats')
      ->fields('wiki_stats', array('today', 'yesterday', 'total'))
        ->condition('nid', $node->book['bid'])
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();

    $header = array(
        array('data' => t('Activity'), 'colspan' => 2),
    );

    $rows = array(
        array(t('Today'), array('data' => $stats['today'], 'class' => 'today-value')),
        array(t('Yesterday'), $stats['yesterday']),
        array(t('All Time'), array('data' => $stats['total'], 'class' => 'total-value')),
    );

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}

/**
 * Stats update needs to run in an ajax callback to bypass page caching
 */
function wiki_ajax_stats($bid) {
  _wiki_stats_increment($bid);

    $stats = db_select('wiki_stats')
      ->fields('wiki_stats', array('today', 'total'))
        ->condition('nid', $bid)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();

    drupal_json_output($stats);
}
```